# How to name a class whose purpose is to hold related objects?

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, naming, naming-standards

I am working in a wizard in WPF application. As the wizard gathers a lot of information I have designed separate view models for each step (view) in a wizard.
But I have to hold all this information in an object to display in a summary screen and push to database when the user reviews the summary and submits.

Example:
Say there is a vehicle registration wizard.

```
class VehicleDetails
   {
     string Name {get;set;}
     int Number {get;set;}
   }

class VehicleOwner
{
  string Name {get;set;}
  string Address {get;set;}
}

Class VehicleFeatures
{
  string Color {get;set;}
  int EngineCapacity {get;set;}
}
```

Now as the user fills all this information step by step I have to hold the information in a seperate instance to summarize and submit.

```
Class Vehicle________ (Master/Container/?)
{
  VehicleDetails Details {get;set;}
  VehicleOwner Owner {get;set;}
  VehicleFeatures Features {get;set;}
}
```

What is the best way I could name so that the furute 'Reader' of this code could understand my intent ? Is there any standard vocabulary for such scenario ?

Comment: What about `Vehicle`?

Comment: How about Vehicle?

Comment: Do you really need separate class for each of those?

Comment: The name of the class is `Vehicle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In layman's terms:**

- Nobody said class members had to be primitives.
- Class members can be of any type, including user-defined types.
- The fact that some members of the class `Vehicle` are user-defined doesn't make `Vehicle` into a `VehicleContainer` or a `VehicleMaster`
- A vehicle container would be a class that containts vehicles, which in this case it is not
- `VehicleMaster` would be... I don't know what that would be.

**Bottom line:** the name of the class should be `Vehicle`.